# How to take only single label,radio button for every increment in a loop for window form c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, radio-button, label

for every question their will be four radio buttons and labels by programming itself (dynamic) we must create radio buttons and labels. is it possible to do in window form but not creating from window design(form)

```
                for (int i = 0, r = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++, r++)
                  {
                    if (r == 0)
                     {
                       Label line = new Label();
                       label20.MaximumSize = new Size(600, 50);
                       label20.AutoSize = true;
                       label20.Text += (r + 1).ToString() + " " + dt.Rows[r]                                      ["Question"].ToString() + " ";
                //#region Answer Type
                if (Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[r]["AnswerType"]) == 0)
                {
                    checkedListBox1.Visible = false;
                    radioButton1.Enabled = false;
                    radioButton2.Enabled = false;
                    radioButton3.Enabled = false;
                    radioButton4.Enabled = false;
                    if (dt.Rows[r]["Option1"].ToString() != null)
                    {
                        label21.Text = dt.Rows[r]["Option1"].ToString();
                    }
                    if (dt.Rows[r]["Option2"].ToString() != null)
                    {
                        label22.Text = dt.Rows[r]["Option2"].ToString();
                    }
                    if (dt.Rows[r]["Option3"].ToString() != null && dt.Rows[r]["Option3"].ToString() != "")
                    {
                        label23.Text = dt.Rows[r]["Option3"].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        radioButton3.Visible = false;
                    }
                    if (dt.Rows[r]["Option4"].ToString() != null && dt.Rows[["Option4"].ToString() != "")
                    {
                        label24.Text = dt.Rows[r]["Option4"].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        radioButton4.Visible = false;
                    }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear can you please take some time to explain exactly what you need? (i.e what part of the code snippet provided doesn't do what you are looking to do), also, I'd recommend taking some time to give your controls explanatory names (for your own benefit)

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to create RadioButtons and Labels dynamically while you're program is running? E.g. after they answer 1 question, you create new labels and new buttons. If so, yes. But i'm not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: for every question their will be four radio buttons and labels by programming itself (dynamic) we must create radio buttons and labels. is it possible to do in window form but not creating from window design(form) @Sayse

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of examples around about how to programatically add controls to forms

Comment: yah dynamically . For every question label must created in this loop only as also radio button @Ralt

Comment: i had tried but not getting values in window form by calling labels and radio buttons dynamically. @Sayse

Comment: you should name your labels properly and why don't you use a usercontrol that handles the radiobuttons and labels? then you dont have to create every single lable yourself in the form

Comment: i can do it but my issue is i need to create 200 labels 96 radio buttons for each label we must assign data table value as also same process for radio button coding will be very huge so i panned to call labels and radio buttons dynamically @SebastianL

Comment: continue for my above comment .... and also when i tried this process window from is not sufficient while creating in the form do u have any idea to increase the size of window form while designing.dynamically i can add vertical scroll and i can move up and down but i need while designing the form  do u have any idea about dis ??@SebastianL

Answer (score 0):

As in my comment i would do it like this:

```
List<myUserControl> ucs = new List<myUserControl>();

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    ucs.Add(new myUserControl(dt.Rows[i]));
}
```

to add those controls to a form i'd use a flowlayoutpanel

```
foreach(myUserControl uc in ucs)
{
    flp.Controls.Add(uc);
}
```

if the form is not big enough you can activate autoscroll in the flowlayoutpanel.